# Is the default mail app on Windows 10 done using HTML5, CSS and javascript?

Tags: windows, win-universal-app

One of my colleague try to convince me that  the default mail app on Windows 10 is done using HTML5, CSS and javascript. But I doubted it and I believe it is written using Windows SDK and C#. Do you have any evidence to show how the mail app was built?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You win. It's not HTML.

You can check by running the app and then examining it in Task Manager. Look at the details and the process name will be WWAHost.exe for an HTML app.

You can get more detail with [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). ProcExp will let you see the DLLs loaded in the process where you can see that it loads Windows.UI.Xaml.dll.

.Net (C#) vs. C++ is trickier, especially since it's likely a mix of both. The .Net Framework engines (mscorwks.dll, etc.) in the process would indicate a .Net app, but I don't believe they'll show up in a .Net native app, and Mail (along with all other .Net Universal Windows apps deployed from the store) will be compiled with .Net Native.

You can also figure out similar information by looking at the app's package in \Program Files\WindowsApps